# No Database selected if retrieving rows from database in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to retrieve rows from database but it returns not database selected but i have defined the database in my class my code is as follows:

```
<?php
 $query="SELECT * FROM product";
 $sql_q=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_q))
    {
        $prodName= $row['product_name']; 
 ?>
 <tr class="odd">
                <td class=" sorting_1"><?=$prodName?></td>

 <?  </tr>  }
?>
```

In the class i have declared that:

```
class DB {
    function __construct(){
        $connection = @mysql_connect(SERVER, USERNAME, PASSWORD) or die('Connection error -> ' . mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db(DATABASE, $connection) or die('Database error -> ' . mysql_error());
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: "*but i have defined the database in my class my code*" — I don't see it being defined anywhere in the code you've posted. You need to establish a MySQL connection (using `mysql_connect()`) and select a database (using `mysql_select_db()`) before you can execute any queries.

Comment: If you insist on using the really old and deprecated `mysql_` commands you should make a connection to the database using the `mysql_connect()` function before trying to execute a query.

Comment: where is your db connection code?

Comment: You should start from [PDO Connection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php).

Comment: Please use **`mysqli_`** functions, `mysql_` is deprecated

Comment: i have edited my code i have used this class and included it.

Comment: But class will not get called magically. You required to initiate that class by creating its object.

Comment: your are not ringing the bell and you want the room to open automatically !! you have to ring the bell - call the class by creating the object. Door will be open - your query will run

Comment: So finally door is opened according to @RickSmarty :P

Answer (score 0):

You haven't connected to your database (that we can see).

You also haven't used mysql_select_db http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php

You need to select your database before you query it.

Also the MySQL extension is deprecated and should not be used. Please look at MySqli:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Or PDO:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

EDIT:  You need to instantiate your class:

$db = new DB();

Comment: `You need to select your database before you query it.`. No this is actually not mandatory. Your query can specify DB to use too.

Comment: True, but if he insists on using MySQl, then it is good practice to select your DB before running queries.

Comment: you need to either select your db or use it in your queries otherwise your query would fail. But it got nothing in common with good practices.

Comment: I have very rarely seen instances where using the MySql extension (now deprecated), you would select the db, IN the query itself?!? Connect -> select db -> run queries.  But we will agree to disagree

Comment: you need to check sql syntax